# How can I control a set of videos with their parent containers?

Tags: javascript, html

JS newbie here. I'm in a situation where I need each video in a set to play on mouseover and pause on mouseout. I use a forEach loop to give this functionality to all of them, but now I need to "move" this functionality to div containers for each video, not the videos themselves.

Here's what I'm starting with:

HTML

```
<video src="/path-to-video" loop></video>
<video src="/path-to-video" loop></video>
<video src="/path-to-video" loop></video>
<video src="/path-to-video" loop></video>
```

JS

```
const videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');

videos.forEach(video => {
    video.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        this.play();
    });

    video.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
        this.pause();
    });
});
```

I need to "transfer" the functionality of the above to a div container for each video. So, when I hover over the video, it is the div container that is actually playing the video, and when I hover away, it is the div container that is pausing the video. So NOT the video itself like it is above.

The HTML would now look like this (essentially):

```
<div class="item">
    <video src="/path-to-video" loop></video>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <video src="/path-to-video" loop></video>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <video src="/path-to-video" loop></video>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <video src="/path-to-video" loop></video>
</div>
```

I tried this JS:

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

items.forEach(item => {
    const video = document.querySelectorAll('video');

    item.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        video.play();
    });

    item.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
        video.pause();
    });
});
```

This did nothing; none of the videos played on hover.

I also tried:

```
document.querySelector('.item').addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    const video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.play();
});

document.querySelector('.item').addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
    const video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.pause();
});
```

This worked as intended on the first video, but not any of the others, and using querySelectorAll made none of them work. Using getElementsByClassName makes none of them work.

I'd prefer to keep the forEach approach but just have each div play and pause its video child using mouseover and mouseout. How could this be achieved? I'm probably not doing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`items` is a `NodeList`, so you are looping over all of the elements with the "item" class. You can use the `querySelector` method on the elements you're iterating over to get that element's child video element. Then, you can call `play()` on that video element.

Basically, you had the right idea, you just need to use `querySelector` on the `item` instead of `document`.

Example:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

items.forEach(item => {
  // see change below
  const video = item.querySelector('video');

  item.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    video.play();
  });

  item.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    video.pause();
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  width: 300px;
}

video {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <video src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4" loop></video>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <video src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4" loop></video>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <video src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4" loop></video>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <video src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4" loop></video>
</div>
```